# Android Studio: Method "createStyleableSymbol" in class XXX has illegal signature "(XXX)XXX"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a project in Android studio and it fails with the following error (during :app:processReleaseResources):

> Method "createStyleableSymbol" in class com/android/ide/common/symbols/Symbol$Companion has illegal signature "(Njava/lang/String;Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;Ljava/util/List;Z)Lcom/android/ide/common/symbols/Symbol$StyleableSymbol;"

Complete text is:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Method "createStyleableSymbol" in class com/android/ide/common/symbols/Symbol$Companion has illegal signature "(Njava/lang/String;Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;Ljava/util/List;Z)Lcom/android/ide/common/symbols/Symbol$StyleableSymbol;"

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

I use:
Grade 4.2.2

I tried:

1. Clean project + Rebuild
2. Invalidate Caches + restart

Any idea on cause and how to solve this ?

Edit (screenshot from the IDE):
[image]

Comment: Did you copy-paste that error message or transcribe it by hand? `Njava/lang/String;` certainly doesn't look right. It should most likely be `Ljava/lang/String;`.

Comment: I copy/pasted it directly from the IDE